# How to get implicit z-index with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, z-index

I have several elements on a page, some have z-index explicitly written in their CSS and some have not. Is it possible to get their visible Z position to, for instance, attach a `data-z-index` to each element? It is not a problem if the original z-index is override by a new order.

Comment: Use `getComputedStyle()` to get the element's actual z-index.

Comment: `getComputedStyle()` returns `auto` when `z-index` is not defined, what I need a number that reflects is the visible order in z.

Comment: You could calculate this from [the stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), however I can't help but wonder, what use case would this have?

Comment: @Etheryte My goal is to give different animations to all the elements on the page depending on their depth. A bit like that https://otherside.otherti.me/